# Adding current row in arcpy.SearchCursor to selection

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, cursor

I want to make a code that select all unique values of a field in a attribute table. However, while everything in the code apparently works, I don't know how to add the current row in the Search Cursor in my selection.

```
    layer = parameters[0].valueAsText
    mylist = []
    rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(layer, fields="Surveyor")
    for row in rows:
        value = row.getValue("Surveyor")
        if value not in mylist:
            mylist.append(value)
            arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(layer, 'ADD_TO_SELECTION')
    arcpy.AddMessage(mylist)
    return
```

On the message (second last line), the program prints a list with 3 unique values. Yet, the code always select every single row. Makes sense, since there was no filter on my SelectLayer, so it just select the whole layer. So I tried using a field with Unique Values:

```
    layer = parameters[0].valueAsText
    mylist = []
    rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(layer, fields="Surveyor, uniqueID")
    for row in rows:
        value = row.getValue("Surveyor")
        myid = row.getValue("uniqueID")
        if value not in mylist:
            mylist.append(value)
            arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(layer, 'ADD_TO_SELECTION', '"uniqueID" = myid')
    arcpy.AddMessage(mylist)
    return
```

But no success, it still selects the whole layer. So, how I make the SelectLayerbyAttribute to add to the selection only the row that the cursor is located?

Comment: First rule of `arcpy.SearchCursor`: Use `arcpy.da.SearchCursor` instead.

Answer (score 2):

"Old-style" search cursors are an artifact of the past.  All supported versions of ArcGIS Desktop and Server offer Data Access cursors, which are faster and more Pythonic (list-oriented).

This is one way to rewrite your code, though there are options for faster runtime execution if you know that the number of IDs to be added is a relatively small set (e.g., less than 100-200).

The original problem was not placing the 'myid' *value* in the query expression.

```py
layer = parameters[0].valueAsText

mylist = []
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer, ['surveyor', 'uniqueID']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        value = row[0]
        myid = row[1]
        if value not in mylist:
            mylist.append(value)
            filterexp = '"uniqueID" = {:d}'.format(myid)
            arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(layer, 'ADD_TO_SELECTION', filterexp)

arcpy.AddMessage(mylist)
return
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
layer = parameters[0].valueAsText

mylist = []
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(layer, fields="surveyor, uniqueID")
for row in rows:
    value = row.getValue("surveyor")
    myid = row.getValue("uniqueID")
    filterexp = '"uniqueID" = ' + str(myid)
    if value not in mylist:
        mylist.append(value)
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(layer, 'ADD_TO_SELECTION', filterexp)
arcpy.AddMessage(mylist)
return
```